# In the Mark Wahlberg version of Planet of the Apes, who was the Great Emancipator?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2001

The final scene of the 2001 production finds Wahlberg being arrested on the steps of the Lincoln Memorial, behind him the statue of the Ape Lincoln.

In that time-line, who did [The Great Emancipator](https://www.historyextra.com/period/victorian/abraham-lincoln-great-emancipator-slavery-what-did-president-do-free-slaves-lucy-worsley/) emancipate?

Comment: Are *all* the historical figures (non-human) apes in that timeline? If so, why ask about Lincoln in particular? We can presume that all real-world historical facts and events have their simian equivalents, right?

Comment: Erm...I think that was the point of the question?

Comment: What I mean is, can't we assume that as illogical as it seems, we are supposed to imagine that *every* historical event occurred with apes filling in for every human being in history?

Comment: @Cascabel - Who do you mean by The Great Emancipator? (Abraham Lincoln? General Thade?) No one in this movie was described as such. Also, no one in that alternate timeline was explicitly said to have been emancipated.

Comment: @Adamant - _"Are all the historical figures (non-human) apes in that timeline?"_ We know almost nothing about that alternate timeline, especially in regard to events that took place in the distant past. It's an open question as to how much or little thought actually went into that ending.

Comment: Aperaham Lincoln, obviously.

Answer (score 4):

This question seems to assume that there actually *was* a Great Emancipator in the alternate timeline. We don't know that such a figure existed in that timeline, or who that person was, if they did exist. We don't even know for sure that Wahlberg's character, Leo Davidson, returned to the same universe that he started out in; some have theorised that he arrived on the Earth of a parallel universe, or on a future version of the Ape Planet.

And that ambiguity about what actually happened at the end was a deliberate choice, incidently. The director, Tim Burton, claimed on the DVD commentary that there was "a thought" behind that ending, suggesting there was a coherent logic to it. However, he chose not to reveal what that logic was, on the basis that he wanted to leave things sufficiently open to interpretation that anyone making a prospective sequel could decide for themselves what direction they wanted to go in.

> I planned the ending out to where, if they wanted to do other movies, you could track this... let's put it that way. Do I want to say where it is? What time it is? What's the date? All of that? Uhhh, no, because I think... let's say Fox wants to make another movie. I don't think personally that way, but let's say they want to make another movie. So I explain this ending. It kind of screws up other things, if they want, you know, to do something. So in other words, it's thought out enough to where it can be explained. But if I want to start explaining it, it might damage something that... again, it's like... first of all, I wouldn't want to... even not wanting to do another movie, I wouldn't want to relate that to somebody else who might, you know, want to do something. So... I can just say that it's been thought out, and there's a thought to it, but... you can figure some things out through the film, but at the same time, there still is... part of what happens for this is that, unlike the first film, there is an unknown. I mean, when Mark looks out at the and is like "What the fuck is this?", that's where it ends, I mean, that is true. It's like, he has no idea where the hell, what happened... and that was part of it for me. I mean, part of that for me is ending up on an image that does have a big question mark on it. And again, it's a fine line about how far you go and how far you don't go. Although, you're maybe asking the wrong person, because sometimes I like to do things as a reaction against other things.
>
> To me, somebody going back and landing on a place where he thinks he's at, and then he finds out he's not there... that to me is logical. I mean, there's a logic to that. I mean, there's less logic to exactly know what he's going back to. So I actually had no problem... I mean, I'm not quite sure what people are responding to, because, for me, I had no problem with the ending. I knew there were several elements that needed to happen. One of them was just an image I had of just complete reversal, of complete, simple reversal that I felt somehow was weird and compelling to me, with the other issues and elements. So, if they do another movie, it's about finding things out, sort of. When I looked at this material, like I said, I thought about alot of different elements, and because it kinda comes back around on itself, you can spiral out on different tangents, if you want, which therefore does leave it open to kinda deal with, which thing are you focusing on here. Which thing do you want to focus on most of all. So, therefore, there is room to, like... if they don't like this aspect of it, you know, you can focus on that aspect of it. So, in my mind, yes, there are ways to deal with the same kind of material without being completely locked in, and still be true to it.
>
> The people, like, wanting to know how and where, and what time this is, and all of that... for me, and I could be the audience of one on this, but I wouldn't have taken it any further. I wouldn't have explained any more, even if I could've, or whatever. To me, it ended up where it should've ended up, and that's where I wanted to end it, is on that sort of vibe.
>
> It was always this basic idea, I mean I remember reading on the Internet and hearing we had five-to-eleven endings, or whatever, and er, no. I think where that maybe started from is that there may've been certain little image changes... there was a thing at Yankee Stadium that we discussed... but it was the same idea. That's where the images may have changed, and there might've even been others that we were discussing, but... in my mind it was always the same idea; this very simple reversal. And that, to me, I thought was compelling and weird, and just this weird thing that felt like it was the right thing to end up on, for this. So, no, there was never all these different endings. We basically shot one ending; we shot it about three quarters of the way though the shoot, and that was it.

Some of the DVD releases of the film did include an insert implying that General Thade somehow managed to travel back to an earlier point in Earth's history than Leo, using the damaged Delta Pod left behind on the Ape Planet.

[image]

However, this was only presented as a possibility, not a fact. And nothing is known as to when exactly Thade arrived on Earth, if he did so, or what precisely happened after he got there, beyond the inscription on the 'Aperaham Lincoln' Memorial cryptically stating that he "saved the planet."

[image]

We can speculate that he might've arrived in the US some time around the 19th century, since the aforementioned memorial implies that he in some way usurped Abraham Lincoln's role in history. But for all we know, he could've arrived before Lincoln was born, and altered history in such a way that Lincoln himself never came to power, or was never born at all. Or he could've arrived *after* Lincoln freed the slaves, and forcibly displaced him.

We simply don't know which (if any) of these scenarios actually transpired. As such, there's no way to tell if anyone was emancipated in that timeline, or *who* did the emancipating, if such an event indeed took place.